# Charactaristics of Certain Hydroxyl Protecting Groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, protecting-groups

I have been reading through Philip J. Kocienski's book *Protecting Groups* to try to better understand some of the characteristics of hydroxy protecting groups. I am looking to understand the compatibility of silyl ethers, alkyl ethers, alkoxymethyl ethers, tetrahydropyranyl, methylthiomethyl ethers, esters, and carbonates with acidic conditions; however, my book is very vague on this. Which of these classes of protecting groups will be compatible with strongly acidic conditions (specifically, I will need it to remain intact in HBr for an addition reaction). I am just looking to know which categories are best for these conditions so I can narrow my search. So far, based on what I have read, the Troc protecting group would best suit strongly acidic conditions; however, it is highly electron withdrawling, which will likely affect an addition reaction I am looking to perform.

[image]

Comment: At what temperature will the HBr reaction be run?

Comment: I will be running the reaction at -10 C in a 30% HBr-acetic acid solution in toluene (an adaption of the following protocol: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed072p848). All future steps are also performed at -10 C.

Comment: Plain old O-benzyl ether will probably stand that pretty well

Comment: Well "protective groups" are not an absolute way of protecting a moiety. It always depends on the reaction conditions you will use later.

Comment: I cannot use a benzyl ether since the product I have to deprotect (I've included an image above - the aliphatic -OH group will have the protecting group-) contains a benzyl ether moiety

Comment: Well you need to make a difference between "strongly acidic" and "strongly acidic with water".

Comment: It would be strongly acidic without water; however, it would involve a protic acid, acetic acid (anhydrous of course), and an alcohol, phloroglucinol.

Comment: @ELIJONES  The molecule you have drawn is a phenyl ether, not a benzyl ether. They react very differently.

Comment: Would a tert-butyl diphenyl silyl ether work in this case? The TBDPS ether has a half-life of about 244 minutes in 1% HCl. Would running a hydrobromination involving a 30% HBr solution in acetic acid diluted to half the initial volume using hexanes for 20 minutes at -10 C likely cause a drastic loss of yield? I understand there may be better protecting groups to withstanding these conditions; however, I don't want to have to worry about using harsh conditions to remove these protecting groups.